# Two Functions need to become one how am i gonna do this

Tags: php, date, variables

```
function friday16mei(){
    $ret= "";
    if(time() <= strtotime('17-05-2014')){
     $ret =   'friday 16 mei';
    }
    return $ret;
}
function getoptions(){
    $ret = "";
    $saturday22 = saturday22march();
    if(strlen($saturday22) > 0){
        $ret .= "<option>" . $saturday22 . "</option>";
    }
    $friday16mei = friday16mei();
    return $ret;
}
$Content= '
<div class="content">
    I am signing up for the following date:<br />
    <select name="date[0]">
        '. getoptions() .'
    </select>
</div>
';
echo $Content;
```

---

I have 2 functions now and they need to become one how am i gonna do this? Do i need parameter for this?

It is so i can add more or edit it in the future.

Comment: what is your actual goal? your functions sound like they could be generalized (eg just give the day as a parameter to a function that returns the date as string or an empty string).

Comment: Agree with @Dehalion, in general, it is better that 1 function does 1 thing (and only 1 thing), it is better to have 2 small functions that you can call independently... so what is the goal of merging them?

Comment: On a sidenote: you might want to make sure you stick to a single language instead of combining two. "Mei" is Dutch, the english equivalent is "May".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store your date checking values and your texts in a array an compare it in a loop instead a method:

```
function getoptions(){
    $check = array(
        '17-05-2014' => 'friday 16 mei',
        '23-03-2014' => 'saturday 22 march'
    );

    $now = time();
    $result = array();
    foreach($check as $date => $text) {
        if($now  <= strtotime($date)) {
            $result[] = $text;
        }
    }

    $html = '';
    foreach($result as $v) {
        $html .= '<option>'.$v.'</option>';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is how i though it needed to be thnxs!